# Google Tag Manager Incomplete Funnel Issue

Tags: google-analytics, magento2, google-tag-manager

i've setuped GTM on my online store (magento2 using a custom extensio). [i've done this on several stores with success]

On one particular store we are getting some issues on the funnels, the Product Views and Transactions arent being recorded.

Below is the GA funnel

[GA Funnel Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r13kp.png)

Using GTM debug, i've isolated the datalayers for the product page and for the success page.
The datalayers are below

--- Product Page dataLayer ---

```
{
  gtm: {start: 1611324270479, uniqueEventId: 4},
  event: 'gtm.load',
  ecommerce: {
    detail: {
      products: [
        {
          name: 'Bracelet',
          id: '501',
          price: '3.90',
          category: 'Man'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

--- Checkout Success Page dataLayer ---

```
{
  gtm: {start: 1611324363183, uniqueEventId: 5},
  event: 'gtm.load',
  ecommerce: {
    purchase: {
      actionField: {
        id: '000000054',
        affiliation: 'Store Name - Store Name - PT',
        revenue: '6.9000',
        coupon: '',
        tax: '1.2900',
        shipping: '2.4400'
      },
      products: [
        {
          name: 'Bracelet',
          id: '501',
          price: '3.17',
          category: 'Man',
          list: 'Man',
          quantity: '1.0000'
        },
        {
          name: 'Watch',
          id: '61',
          price: '20.24',
          category: 'Man',
          list: 'Man',
          quantity: '1.0000'
        }
      ]
    },
    currencyCode: 'EUR'
  }
}
```

Can someone help me understand why this 2 steps arent being populated with data.

Thanks

Comment: Try to add code of the other working steps to see if there are any differences that can help you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should your event for the Checkout Success be `event: 'purchase'` and not `event: 'gtm.load'`.